# RedisSessionProvider and Async methods

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, redis

So, first a disclaimer - i'm new to this Async programming thing. So before i begin implementation into my current project i have been running a bunch of tests to iron out the kinks and gain a better understanding of the whole thing.

I ran into a kink today related to **HttpContext.Current.Session** being null which happens to be all over my current code base.

Here is my little test app:

```
public partial class RandomTests : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine("Blend dual call start");
        Debug.WriteLine("Operation complete. Returned: " + await BlendDualCall() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff"));
        Debug.WriteLine("Blend dual call complete");
        Debug.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    public async Task<string> BlendDualCall()
    {
        var cTask = Task.Run(() => YLogin(1000));
        var fTask = Task.Run(() => FLogin(2000));

        Debug.WriteLine("Awaiting results.");
        var yResult = await cTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("YLogin result returned at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff"));
        var fResult = await fTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("FLogin result returned at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff"));

        return yResult + "   " + fResult;
    }

    #region Non-Async Methods

    public string FLogin(int waitTime)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FLogin process executed on thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);

        //Session is null here
        return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "_" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 
    }

    public string YLogin(int waitTime)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("YLogin process executed on thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);

        //Session is not null here (System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState). Whats the difference?
        return Session.SessionID + "_" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Custom SessionState provider in web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisSessionProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="******" port="***" accessKey="********" ssl="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I'm looking for some understand as to what is happening with SessionState and why it is null within a async call. Interestingly enough HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is null but Session.SessionID is not null, i suspect it is using a different SessionState provider? On that topic it is important to note that i'm using RedisSessionProvider as a custom SessionState provider (for Azure). Is there something i need to do with the RedisSessionProvider to allow it to handle asynchronous calls? Can someone point me in the right direction and maybe a small explaination on how SessionState handles async calls?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions cannot be shared across multiple threads simultaneously. This is a limitation of all ASP.NET sessions, not just Redis ones.

The core problem is the use of `Task.Run`. `Task.Run` will make ASP.NET use *multiple* threads per request, which is a pretty bad idea since it severely impacts your scalability. `Task.Run` also explicitly steps outside the request context, so `HttpContext.Current` will be `null` - this is by design.

The best solution is to remove all calls to `Task.Run`. You can perform multiple concurrent asynchronous operations just fine - if they're actually asynchronous (not just running on a background thread). E.g.:

```
// True asynchronous calls
public async Task<string> FLogin(int waitTime)
{
  await Task.Delay(waitTime);
  return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "_" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 
}

public async Task<string> BlendDualCall()
{
  var cTask = YLogin(1000);
  var fTask = FLogin(2000);
  ...
}
```

If they're not truly asynchronous, then the next best solution is to execute them one at a time. E.g.:

```
public string FLogin(int waitTime);
public string BlendDualCall()
{
  var yResult = YLogin(1000);
  var fResult = FLogin(2000);
  ...
}
```

If you absolutely **must** do parallel code on the server (again, I really can't recommend this), then you'll need to pull all the data you need out of the session before starting the parallel work. E.g.:

```
public string FLogin(int waitTime, string sessionId)
{
  Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
  return sessionID + "_" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 
}
public string BlendDualCall()
{
  var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString();
  var cTask = Task.Run(() => YLogin(1000, sessionId));
  var fTask = Task.Run(() => FLogin(2000, sessionId));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply, i'm beginning to understand some more. So it sounds to me that the best course of action is to convert most of my code to true async methods. Maybe a stupid questions but when doing something like this what should i keep in mind when using the await call? And what if there is nothing in the method that should or can be awaited on? Is this the zombie code that everyone talks about? Am i going to need to convert every method being called within the method i am converting?

Comment: I recommend starting at the "leaves". That is, code that does I/O should be converted to use `await` at the very lowest level - sending the HTTP request, querying the database, etc. Then let `async` grow out from there.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.